# Getting Excel Named Ranges into JSON in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, excel

I am trying to get all the named ranges from an Excel Workbook into a JSON format.

So far, I can get all the named ranges and get the data from them. However... I'm not able to handle the varying data types and/or figure out how to properly nest into JSON format. It seems like I should be able to add to a nested list or something and then use a JSON serializer? Not sure that's possible.

All the named ranges I care about have the same format... something like this:
`my_[indicator]_[user-specified-value]`

Where `[indicator]` is always `Settings`, `Input`, or `Output`

And `[user-specified-value]` could be any string with only text and numbers (ie - A-Z, a-z, 0-9)

For instance, `my_Input_Months` equals `4`

However, in this case, it's an `int` but can also be `string` or any other data type.

It can also be an array, with either one or two dimensions.

Here's the C# code I have that grabs the data from all the named ranges in the workbook:

```
private void createJsonFormat()
{
    object missing = Type.Missing;

    // GET THE CURRENT WORKBOOK
    Excel.Workbook wb = (Excel.Workbook)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;

    // FIND OUT HOW MANY NAMED RANGES ARE IN THE WORKBOOK
    int intNames = wb.Names.Count;

    if (intNames != 0)
    {
        foreach (Excel.Name name in wb.Names)
        {
            string strValue = name.Value;
            string strLinkName = name.Name;
            if (strValue != "=#REF!#REF!")
            {
                strAddress = name.RefersToRange.Cells.get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, missing, missing);
                strSheetName = name.RefersToRange.Cells.Worksheet.Name;
            }

            object objValue = name.RefersToRange.Value;
            string strValue2 = name.RefersToRange.Value2.ToString();

            string[] parts = strLinkName.Split(new char[] { '_' });

            if (parts[0] == "my")
            {
                switch (parts[1])
                {
                    case "Settings":
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(strLinkName + ": " + strValue2);
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Input":
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(strLinkName + ": " + strValue2);
                            break;
                        }
                    case "Output":
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(strLinkName + ": " + strValue2);
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        {
                            // DON'T CARE ABOUT THESE NAMED RANGES
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }

            if (strValue2 == "System.Object[,]")
            {
                string strValueHolder = string.Empty;

                int i = 0;

                foreach (var varValue3 in (dynamic)objValue)
                {

                    if (varValue3.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            strValueHolder = varValue3.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            strValueHolder = strValueHolder + ", " + varValue3.ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    i++;
                }

                Debug.WriteLine(strValueHolder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output from this is:

```
my_Input_Months: 4
my_Input_InitialAmt: 1000
my_Input_GrowthRate: 0.0025
my_Input_StartDate: 42736
my_Output_Dates: System.Object[,]
1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM, 2/28/2017 12:00:00 AM, 3/31/2017 12:00:00 AM, 4/30/2017 12:00:00 AM
my_Output_GrossAmts: System.Object[,]
1000, 1002.5, 1005.00625, 1007.518765625
my_Settings_ItemName: Best Name
my_Settings_ItemTypeId: 1
```

So if my data was always exactly the same, I guess I could piece together the strings to make it look like JSON or even maybe create a class to hold the data, but the fact that the data types change frequently AND I never know whether I'm going to get a single value, a 1-dimensional array, or a 2-dimensional array, really makes it difficult to build a structure (I think).

Any help would be great.

Comment: Maybe something like `{name: "rangeNameHere", values: [{r:1, c:1,v:"valuehere"}, {r:2,c:1,v:"value2here"} ] }`  Better to treat your single-cell ranges as a one-element array than have two types of object in your JSON.

Comment: Easiest is probably to put the values in a `Dictionary<string, object>` then serialize the dictionary using [tag:javascriptserializer] or [tag:json.net].

Comment: @dbc - the `Dictionary` + `json.net` path worked for me... at least it got me the next step with minimal programming! thanks!